# Best practice for the user authentication on JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

i search for the best way how i can make a user authentication in my JSF Webproject. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0) very good Example from BalusC at stockoverflow (by the way Thank you BalusC). But i dont understand this System.

I have written a registration page. After the registration the user is into my database. But who can i use the j_security_check to check the the user from my database?

In my webproject i don't have a site for users and for non-users. When a user is loged in so he see more options for example he can post a text. Who can i check this? Can i save the User Class with the userdata at the login and check:

```
if(user != null){
 <h:inputText value="User Only Text" id="text"  />
}
```

But i think this way is not very elegant. Also my Question is what is the best way to make a user login and show the valid user more options on the webpage than a non-user.

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can I use the j_security_check to check the the user from my database?

This [article](http://www.developinjava.com/features/47-enterprise-java/106-securing-a-web-application-on-glassfish-using-jaas-pt-2.html) explains how to use HTTP FORM based authentication in conjunction with JDBC realms within Glassfish.

> what is the best way to make a user login and show the valid user more options on the webpage than a non-user.

Basically, you need to check if the user has the appropriate role to see the "options". Have a look at `ExternalContext#isUserInRole(String)`

Comment: @Pascal: Would you like to say something about when it is good to move from container based security to alternatives like shiro or others? See more focussed question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782720/when-to-move-from-container-managed-security-to-alternatives-like-apache-shiro

Answer (score 5):

Just declare `user` as a session scoped managed bean and make use of the component's `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:inputText value="User Only Text" id="text" rendered="#{user != null}" />
```

Comment: And how do i say that the User Class is load into the session scoped after login?

Comment: Either using sort of `UserManager` session bean with `login()` method and `user` property so that you can use `#{userManager.user != null}`, or by doing `externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user)` in login method of a bean.