# authorization in JSF2

Tags: authorization, jsf-2

what is the best way to implement authorization in JSF2?
through, servlet filter, phase listener or ther is something new that I am not aware of?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2207147/2214674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pieces to this: Authentication, and Authorisation.

First Authentication:  You can configure your web.xml to perform JAAS-based authentication according to a url pattern.  Alternatively, if url-based authentication is too coarse-grained for you, you could do this manually with a PhaseListener or page actions using the HttpServletRequest login() method (new in Servlet 3.0).  You can access this method through the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()`.

Once you are authenticated to a JASS realm, you can consider role based authorisation.  Again there are a number of options:

1. You can restrict page access to specified roles in the web.xml according to a url-pattern
2. You can use the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().isUserInRole("role")` to programmatically access the current role in your backing beans.
3. You can conditionally render components in the view using Expression Language, based on the user role.  (Seam has the s:hasRole EL expression, IceFaces has the renderedOnUserRole attribute, or you can expose the role from your own backing bean).