# Forbid the access to pages using navigation rules - JSF

Tags: jsf

Is possible to forbid the access to some pages using just navigation rules? What I want to do is to forbid the access of some users to some pages and if they type the URL of these pages in url bar to be redirected to an error page. I know that I can do it using filters, but I want to know if is the any chance to do it only by using navigation rules.

Comment: You can also 'just'  do it in the web.xml. Navigation rules are used less and less.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [authorization in JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956640/authorization-in-jsf2)

Comment: Navigation rules are used to direct a user from one page to the other (optionally with conditions), I'm sure this can be done role based. But they can't be used to prevent a user from invoking an abitrary URL (authoriztion). Why do you want to do that? Seemes to be an [xy-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.