# Authentication / Authorization in JSF web application?

Tags: java, authentication, jsf, authorization, jsf-2

I found there are 2 types of authentication mechanism in JSF.

1. JAAS (Java Authentication and Authorization Service)
2. Container managed

(please correct if I am wrong)

I tried searching for a better tutorial that guide to learn any of those method. Unfortunately I was ended up in many of uncompleted lessons. Can any one provide me a solid tutorial or any guide where I can catch the rope.

Comment: You should be more precise about your environment. 
Are you using JavaEE6/JSF2? There is a related discussion on Stackoverflow about authentication in this environment: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0

Comment: I am using JavaEE6/JSF2 with GlasfissV3 server.

Comment: there is a tutorial available for authenticate and authorize users in a Java EE 6 using JSF: http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::NO:24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:6517,2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not just 2 types of authentication mechanisms (regardless of JSF). The Oracle (SUN) documentation is actually very good and I would recommend it:

[Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html)

It discusses how to address security requirements in web tier and enterprise tier applications. Namely:

1. [Getting
   Started Securing Web
   Applications](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) - discusses and
   provides examples for adding
   security to web components such as
   servlets.
2. [Getting
   Started Securing Enterprise
   Applications](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbyk.html) - discusses adding
   security to Java EE components such
   as enterprise beans and application
   clients.

Comment: Thaaaks for the link Ross. I will check it and come back. Do you know any other Tutorial other than the Documentation?

Comment: The following link covers form based authentication for a web application that is deployed to Tomcat or GlassFish: http://monstersandwich.blogspot.com/2010/03/shopping-cart-web-application-security.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ross. This is a nice tutorial creating a full JSP app. Still, this is not covering the authentication in detail. It has an overall summary with code download only. Any way thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Correct name is JAAS (Java Authentication and Authorization Service) not JASS.

Have you [been here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/index.html)?

Regards