# Problem with activatin FORM authentfication with JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf

[Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0)

I tried this solution. But if i put this to my config

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>sql</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/index.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

instead of

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>sql</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

the login popup of basic auth doesn't show up anymore.. which was what i aspected. 
But the Login Page which then comes has no Inputfields.. none of the faclet code had been executed. how could that be?

my login.xhtml code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <form action="j_security_check" method="post">
            <h:outputLabel for="j_username">Username:</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" />
            <h:message for="j_username" />
            <br />
            <h:outputLabel for="j_password">Password:</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" />
            <h:message for="j_password" />
            <br />
            <h:commandButton value="Login" />
        </form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Thats all what is displayed

```
Username:
Password:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, the `FacesServlet` is not been invoked. As another evidence, rightclick page in browser, choose *View source* and you'll see that JSF tags are not been processed. The `FacesServlet` is the one responsible for that.

You need to change the URL of the login page to match the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`. If that is for example `*.jsf`, then update as follows:

```
<form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
```

Comment: Okay it was   <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
Thanks you pushed me in the right direction.. I forgt the Faces Servlet which autmaticly maps all Faclets! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You can alternatively also map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`, then you have never to worry about this all.

Comment: i thougth this mapping is on a virtual directory ??     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> would work?

Comment: Well, it's just the `url-pattern` on which the servlet should kick in. The servlet itself will determine the final XHTML resource based on its own `url-pattern` and the request URL.