# how to add a f:ajax tag to an h:link?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have this:

```
<h:link value="Sign In" outcome="login.jsp" />
```

When the link is clicked it navigates to login.jsp.  Works fine.

I'd also like a method in a bean to get called on the click, so I tried this:

```
<h:link value="Sign In" outcome="login.jsp" />
  <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{loginHandler.dismissSignUpDialog}" />
</h:link>
```

But it never calls the method.  The method looks like this:

```
public void dismissSignUpDialog(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    setSignUpDialogDismissed(true);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` indeed doesn't work on `<h:link>` that way. Use `<h:commandLink>` instead.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Sign In" action="login.jsp?faces-redirect=true" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{loginHandler.dismissSignUpDialog}" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

By the way, why are you still using JSP instead of Facelets?

Comment: Thanks.  That explains things.  I have two pages login.jsp and loginError.jsp that are configured as the two pages in the <login-config> in the web.xml.  All the pages in my application are Facelets/XHTML but these two pages are JSP -- originally because my understanding was I could not use a "JSF" page for the login page.  Any suggestions in this area?

Comment: Why not? You've all freedom to write plain HTML in a Facelet file. You can even use JSF components in a plain HTML GET form. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147

Comment: There is a small typo in the code, and SO doesn't allow me to make edits smaller than 6 character. There is a closing tag for h:commandLink after action has been defined; slash should be removed. BTW BalusC rocks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be far better off using an `<h:commandLink>` whose action is set to your method, then alter the method to return String corresponding to your outcome.  That is:

```
 <h:commandLink value="Sign In" action="#{loginHandler.dismissSignUpdialog}" />
```

And the bean:

```
 public String dismissSignUpDialog() {
     setUpDialogDismissed(true);
     return "login";
 }
```