# Ajax h:link doesn't call listener function

Tags: jsf, xhtml, glassfish

When I click on the link it does nothing and I found no error or exception  in glassfish log. I tried commandbutton before but when I use form tag the portlet displays the table with exception below it unSupportedOperation. does anyone know a solution or another option?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:aui="http://liferay.com/faces/aui"
    xmlns:aui-cc="http://liferay.com/faces/aui-cc"
    xmlns:liferay-ui="http://liferay.com/faces/ui"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">



    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{!usersViewBean.formRendered}">
        <aui:row>
            <aui:col styleClass="aui-w100 pfusers">
                <p:dataTable id="users" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top"
                    selection="#{usersModelBean.selectedUser}"
                    value="#{usersModelBean.userDataModel}" var="user">

                    <p:column id="ID" headerText="ID">
                        <h:outputText id="IDCell" value="#{user.userId}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="screenName" headerText="Name">
                        <h:outputText id="screenNameCell" value="#{user.screenName}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="Deactivate2" headerText="Deactivate">
                        <h:link value="Deactivate please">
                            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{usersModelBean.deactivate}" />
                        </h:link>
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>

            </aui:col>
        </aui:row>
    </h:panelGroup>


</ui:composition>
```

When I add  tag it produces UnsupportedOperationException with stack trace:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       at javax.faces.context.ExternalContext.getClientWindow(ExternalContext.java:1500)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.StateHelper.writeClientWindowField(StateHelper.java:315)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:278)
>       at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:126)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:473)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.ViewHandlerCompatImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerCompatImpl.java:52)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:227)
>       at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.execute(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:85)
>       at com.liferay.faces.bridge.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:112)
>       at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:255)
>       at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
>       at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:204)
>       at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:55)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:112)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:583)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:656)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:362)
>       at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1201)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.include(DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.java:55)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:655)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:138)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
>       at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
>       at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.velocity.TemplateProcessor.processMax(TemplateProcessor.java:171)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.doInvoke(UberspectImpl.java:389)
>       at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:378)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:270)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:262)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:342)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:336)
>       at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:328)
>       at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:235)
>       at com.liferay.portal.velocity.VelocityTemplate.processTemplate(VelocityTemplate.java:112)
>       at com.liferay.portal.template.AbstractTemplate.processTemplate(AbstractTemplate.java:108)
>       at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:375)
>       at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePageImpl.java:284)
>       at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.getProcessedTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:96)
>       at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageUtil.getProcessedTemplate(RuntimePageUtil.java:38)
>       at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.control_005fpanel_jsp._jspService(control_005fpanel_jsp.java:824)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
>       at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:302)
>       at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:405)
>       at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:200)
>       at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:95)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
>       at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:178)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>       at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:549)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:526)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:873)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:156)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:359)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:293)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:243)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:86)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:267)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
>       at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:226)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a f:ajax tag to an h:link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001324/how-to-add-a-fajax-tag-to-an-hlink)

Comment: Please do a little searching in stackoverflow. Though I did not know the answer, I found duplicate posts within a few minutes

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried the link you posted but as I said before when I put <form> tag in the xhtml it produces an error on the page under the table. I will add it up