# How to use HttpServletRequest#login() programmatic login with SHA-256 configured security realm

Tags: security, jsf, jsf-2, glassfish-3, servlet-3.0

i have read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2207147/921535), i am using glassfish 3.1.1 security realm configured with sha-256 digest algorithm. is there any tutorial about this ? maybe i am blethering, i am  trying to login with this code:

```
public void login() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    boolean committed = false;
    try {
        FacesMessage msg = null;
        EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();
        entr.begin();
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(password.getBytes());
            byte byteData[] = md.digest();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            password = sb.toString();
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM EntityUser u WHERE u.userName = :userName AND u.password = :password")
                    .setParameter("userName", userName).setParameter("password", password);
            long result = (long)query.getSingleResult();
            if (result == 1) {
                request.login(userName, password);
                msg = new FacesMessage();
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
                msg.setSummary("You are logged in");
            }
            entr.commit();
            committed = true;
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("wrong username or password"));
        }
        finally {
            if (!committed) entr.rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

result variable returns 1, but request.login(userName, password); method in if condition always throws servletexception.

Comment: I have the same problem: form authentication (j_security_check) actually works, but calling request.login() doesn't. How did you solve it?

Comment: I did not solve. I'm not using jsf anymore

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the exception stacktrace? That way it would be easier to understand the source of the exception. But judging from your currently supplied code, you should supply in

```
request.login(userName, password);
```

the password as the plain-text password and not the hashed password.

```
Interface HttpServletRequest
ServletException - if the configured login mechanism does not support username password
authentication, or if a non-null caller identity had already been established (prior to 
the call to login), or if validation of the provided username and password fails.
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of reasons that login fails. You've just checked if appropriate user and password are in table. Glassfish makes two queries - in authenticate process - to two tables. One to table specified as `userTable`, and second to `groupTable` which are determined in security realm definition. Check if web.xml and glassfish-web.xml are correct too.

Comment: i already can login with glassfish form authentication. i want to login programmatically

Answer (score 0):

the questioned problem is whole about method

> request.login(userName, password);

Author made everything right, even his own authentication way of working with users database, but *request.login* needs for authentication realm be set up, to be used by this method. And you have your own, you dont need separate *request.login* authentication. For the case you need it - thats how you do it [jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3](http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html)

So, after you get the result=1, you set up your `context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", u);`
and send redirection            `context.getExternalContext().redirect(context.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "какой-то модуль.xhtml");`

and use webfilter to block access to /Pages/*.xhtml without logging in.

```
@WebFilter("/Pages/*")
    public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
            User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");         
            if(user != null){
                chain.doFilter(request,response);
            }  
            else res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/запрос_учетных_данных.xhtml");
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }
    }
```