# JSF Authentication: cannot intercept error messages

Tags: jsf, authentication, primefaces, j-security-check

I have developed a simple login form to be used in my JSF + PrimeFaces page:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post"> 
    <p:dialog modal="true" header="Login" widgetVar="loginDlg">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">  
            <h:outputLabel for="j_username">Username:</h:outputLabel> 
            <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" /> 
            <h:message for="j_username" /> 
            <h:outputLabel for="j_password">Password:</h:outputLabel> 
            <h:inputSecret id="j_password" required="true" /> 
            <h:message for="j_password" /> 
            <br /> 
            <h:commandButton value="Login" /> 
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>                
</form>
```

Tried with an empty password, but the missing password (that is required) is not caught by `h:message` component. I have also switched to a `p:commandButton` thinking that the problem could have been in the Ajax behaviour of the button, but the page is not rendered because PrimeFaces complains about the CommandButton not being inside a form element. The exception thrown by the container is:

```
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Access denied on empty password for user pippo
```

To summarize, I have 2 questions:

1. Why the missing password doesn't produce a message before the form is submitted?
2. How can I catch a LoginException and display the error message inside the dialog?

Comment: Try to put there `<h:messages />`, this should intercept all error messages on whole page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `j_security_check` request is handled by the web container, not by JSF. That explains that the  `required="true"` won't work. It works only when you use JSF `<h:form>` and programmatic login by `HttpServletRequest#login()` in the action method associated with the command button.

Best what you can do is to confiure a `<form-error-page>` in `web.xml` pointing to the very same URL as the `<form-login-page>`. You could then check if the request has been forwarded by `j_security_check` itself, which would mean that a login error has occurred.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path'] == '/j_security_check'}">
    <h:outputText value="Unknown login, please try again" styleClass="error" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Use this instead of the `<h:message>`.

As to why `<p:commandButton>` complains that there's no form is simply because you didn't use `<h:form>`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that `<form>` (or `<h:form>` whenever you would decide to switch to programmatic login) can better be placed in the body of `<p:dialog>`, not outside. The `<p:dialog>` can by JS be relocated to end of body which would cause it not to be in a form anymore.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. In this case I'll go with pure JSF login form and a session bean for authentication like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147