# JSF FacesContext#addMessage is not displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367152/jsf-authentication-cannot-intercept-error-messages)  I had the problem of displaying validation messages from a Login form. That issue is now solved, but this time I am not able to display a custom message with `FacesContex#addMessage`.

Using JSF + PrimeFaces.

```
<p:dialog header="Login" widgetVar="loginDlg">
    <h:form id="loginForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
            <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" id="username" required="true" label="username" />
            <p:message for="username" />
            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password" required="true" label="password" />
            <p:message for="password" />
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Login" id="loginDlgButton" update=":loginForm,:welcomeMsg" actionListener="#{loginBean.login}"
                                    oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"/>
                <p:message for="loginDlgButton" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

In **LoginBean** (a `SessionScoped` `ManagedBean`):

```
public void login() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    RequestContext rContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest(); 
    try { 
        request.login(this.username, this.password); 
        rContext.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", true);
    } catch (ServletException e) { 
        rContext.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", false);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login Error", "Invalid credentials")); 
    } 
}
```

This code, when validation succeeds and login fails, should display the "Invalid credential" message, but doesn't. Moreover, somewhere in the body of my web page, I have also added this line:

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
```

but my message isn't displayed even there.

[Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29) say that

> If clientId is null, this FacesMessage is assumed to not be associated with any specific component instance

But I can't understand what this means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

place `<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />` inside your `form` or inside some wrapper that is being updated by `update` of your commandButton , or place `loginDlgButton` instead of `null` in `context.addMessage(...`

Comment: Thanks Daniel. See my comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a p:messages tag in your code. It is not the same as the p:message tag. p:message is attached to another component and is displayed as part of validation. The p:messages (or p:growl) component is what you are updating in your bean. Try adding a messages or growl component like this:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
<p:growl id="messageGrowl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />
<h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
```

Comment: My bad. It was already working but the answer was a bit late and / or I hadn't seen it! So, the message is caught by the p:messages tag. But, how to catch the message with a non-global p:message tag without placing the componentId in the bean?

Comment: I think you are asking how to catch the message and display on the dialog? Put a p:messages on the p:dialog. You can then add that to your update list on the command button. If there is a message sent back in the context it will update that one. You will probably need to turn off the autoUpdate="true" on your other messages component or both will be updated.