# Using servlet to log user out in Java EE application

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish-3

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0) answer I tried to logout.

**Servlet Code:**

```
@WebServlet(name = "LogoutServlet", urlPatterns = {"/logout"})
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(user.class);

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Destroys the session for this user.
        if (request.getSession(false) != null) {
            request.getSession(false).invalidate();
        }

        // Redirects back to the initial page.
        logger.warn(request.getContextPath());
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());

    }
}
```

**View Code:**

```
<h:form>
      <h:commandButton value="Logout" action="/logout"/>
</h:form>
```

**Error:**

```
Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/Admin/appManager.xhtml' for action '/logout' with outcome '/logout'
```

I don't think servlet is taking the request with "/logout" url pattern. what have I done incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSF, the `action` is not the URL of the next servlet to be called. Rather than that, it defines navigation rules either through faces-config or directly from the backing beans.

The message tells you that your app has no matching for an action `logout` from your `.xhtml` page.

I would do something like

```
<h:commandButton value="Logout" action="#{backingBean.logout()}"/>
```

where you have a `ManagedBean` `BackingBean` with the method `logout()` and which returns the URL to the "goodbye" address.

Note: If you want to do the operation from a servlet, you should use regular html tags (`<a>`, `<button>` instead of JSF components) to link to it.

Comment: Is it fair to use single backing bean with logout method in all pages. I may have lot of pages and each page calling to same backing beans method

Comment: Yes. In any page you can use multiple backing beans; either for data or actions. And reciprocally, you can use any bean from any page.

Comment: +1 helpful :) Can you provide simple example with <a> tag and servlet?

Comment: Use the `<a>` tag as if it was plain HTML. In fact it is just the HTML tag.

Comment: Just found about h:outputLink, to generate the link directly from JSF. Needed if you need to pass a parameter value through EL. http://marceloagustini.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink/