# JSF / Java EE form vs programmatic authentication

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, authentication

I have been experimenting with the substance of this question ([JSF / Java EE login without requiring a protected resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605277/jsf-java-ee-login-without-requiring-a-protected-resource)).

If I set up a sample application using BASIC authentication, with one public page (/public.xhtml), and one protected page (/protected/private.xhtml), and I have a link from the first page to the second (as shown below), everything works perfectly.

```
<h:commandButton value="Go Private" action="/protected/private?faces-redirect=true" />
```

However, if I remove the `login-config` and replace the above button with:

```
<h:commandButton value="Go Private" action="#{mybean.login}" />
```

...and #{mybean.login} looks something like this...

```
public String login() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ...
    try {
        request.login("known username", "known password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle unknown credentials
    }
    return "/protected/private?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

In this case, the login succeeds (no exception from `request.login()`), but the browser shows a "forbidden resource" page.

Can anyone shed any light on the difference between the two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpServletRequest#login()` programmatic login works only with `FORM` based authentication configuration. Removing the `<login-config>` would make it to default to `BASIC` and thus the `login()` will never work. The `login()` basically sets the user in the session, however the `BASIC` authentication basically checks the `Authenticate` HTTP request header, not the session.

Put that `<login-config>` back and set it to `FORM` if you want to utilize `login()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I haven't tried your solution yet, but my understanding was that `HttpServletRequest#login()` was an alternative to FORM based authentication. According to the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html), the login method __allows an application to collect username and password information as an alternative to specifying form-based authentication in an application deployment descriptor__. Do you believe your answer is still correct?

Answer (score -1):

Where it is:

```
<h:commandButton value="Go Private" action="#{mybean.login}" />
```

it should be:

```
<h:commandButton value="Go Private" action="#{mybean.login()}" />
```

if you want to use the login methode.

But maybe your mybean also has

```
String private login;
public String getLogin(){ return this.login ;}
```

and you've loaded the var with the desired response.