# j_security_check with Primefaces

Tags: java, authentication, jsf-2, primefaces, jaas

How to implement **j_security_check** with **Primefaces**? Normally in **JSP** if you want to use **JAAS** for login, the login form generally is:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
   Username:<input type="text" name="j_username"><br>
   Password:<input type="password" name="j_password">
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

But how do we implement it in JSF or in Primefaces!

- What will be the action
- How do we get rid of id or name like `formId:componentId`
- Also the `p:commandButton` is ajaxified in Primefaces by default, so how does it
  submit the form in non-ajax way

I had a requirement to implement the **JAAS** form authentication with **Primefaces** and I am sharing the solution here; it might come handy to someone.

Comment: Related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is pretty straightforward.

- You need to define the `h:form` with `prependId="false"`, so that it will not generate id or name of the component as `formId:componentId`.
- You need to defined the `action="j_security_check"` in the `h:form` as `onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';"`
- Set the `ajax` attribute of the `p:commandButton` to `false`, so that the form doesn't get submitted in ajax way.

That's it. Here is the complete code of the login form which can be replaced by the aforesaid form:

```
<h:form id="login" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
        <p:inputText id="j_username" name="j_username" />            
        <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
        <p:password id="j_password" name="j_password"/>
        <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" ajax="false"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can just use `<form>` instead of `<h:form>`. No need for nasty JS code (which could at its own also be more simplified by removing `document.getElementById('login').` part).

Comment: @BalusC sorry for the late comment but it looks like neither is the correct solution. I agree that the javascript is ugly - but if you use only `<form>` you can't use `id="submit"` in the `p:commandButton` and therefore the login won't work.... any idea if there is a cleaner solution?

Comment: @OschtärEi: Just use `<input type="submit">` with PF style classes on it.

Comment: if you don't need an `id` for `<h:form>` just use `<h:form onsubmit="this.action='j_security_check';">`

Answer (score 2):

There is working (with Primefaces 5) code (removed name attributes from p:inputText and p:password, removed suggested by BalusC part):

```
<h:form id="login" onsubmit="action='j_security_check';" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
        <p:inputText id="j_username" />            
        <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
        <p:password id="j_password" />
        <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" ajax="false"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```