# JAAS + Primefaces: Login form not redirecting to error page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I believe that you will be able to help me with the below problem.

I'm starting my adventure with Java EE and Primefaces and need a bit of help to understand/fix the problem.

So I've created login module using Jaas and below configuration:

web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>authRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/public/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

login_page_1.xhtml

```
<p:panel header="Login From">
    <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
        Username: <input type="text" name="j_username" />
        Password: <input type="password" name="j_password" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form> 
</p:panel>
```

This configuration work just great however as I'm using primefaces as front-end framework I would like to make my page look better. I found below resolution:

login_page_2.xhtml

```
<p:panel header="Login From">
    <h:form id="loginForm" onsubmit="document.getElementById('loginForm').action='j_security_check';" prependId="false">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2"> 
            <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Email" />
            <p:inputText id="j_username" />

            <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Passwort" />
            <p:password id="j_password"/>

            <p:commandButton id="login" value="Login" ajax="false" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

The problem is that when I use `login_page_1.xhtml` and put wrong credentials (wrong username/password) I got redirected to `errorLogin.xhtml` (this is desirable behavior) however when I use `login_page_2.xhtml` I get below erorr

```
An Error Occurred:

Index: 0, Size: 0

Warning:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
Warning:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of RESTORE_VIEW 1 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Unexpected error restoring state for component with id j_idt6.  Cause: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
FATAL:   Unexpected error restoring state for component with id j_idt6.  Cause: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id j_idt6.  Cause: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.
```

I would be grateful for any help !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13620288/3324704

Comment: Thanks mate, but I've used this answer and it's not working in 100%.

Comment: Perhaps you should be considering programmatic login instead

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the attribute onsubmit and prependId.
Something like this should work..You need to implement a login method though.

```
<p:panel header="Login From">
    <h:form id="loginForm" >
        <p:panelGrid columns="2"> 
            <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Email" />
            <p:inputText id="j_username" />

            <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Passwort" />
            <p:password id="j_password"/>

            <p:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{aMethod}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```