# Retrieve requested URL before JAAS redirect it

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, authentication, jaas

Is that possible to retrieve the user's requested URL before the JAAS redirect it?

my web.xml is like this:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

So, when I'm not logged and try to go at ex. `www.blah.com/myApp/users.jsf`
then the app redirect me to **login.jsf** but the url still the same that the user requested.

then I fill the login form and click Login, that goes to my backbean where a call my loginModule and callbackHandler ex.:

```
public String actionLogin(){
   //do my login and stuff
   return "page that user requested";
}
```

I tried many ways to get the user's requested page. `request.getRequestURL()`

all returned me : `www.blah.com/myApp/login.jsf`

any way to get the requested page? `www.blah.com/myApp/users.jsf`

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login page is internally opened by a server-side forward by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). This thus means that the initially requested page is available as a request attribute with the name as specified in [`RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI) constant. In JSF terms, that's thus available as follows:

```
String originalURI = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
String originalQuery = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_QUERY_STRING);

if (originalQuery != null) {
    originalURI+= "?" + originalQuery;
}
```

*(keep in mind to have a fallback URL for the case it returns `null`, i.e. when it's been opened directly without hitting a restricted URL first)*

The best place to collect it would be the (post)constructor of a `@ViewScoped` bean associated with the login page.

#### See also:

- [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147)

Comment: Perfectly , but some pages I have escop.jsf?value=some-thing

possible to gel all url plus params ?

Comment: They're available by `FORWARD_QUERY_STRING` constant. See updated answer.

Comment: More than perfect!!!! I apreciate you pacience and your goodwill. here in my departament you won a lot of fans! thanks a lot and i wish you a great xmas and happy new year! greating from Rio de Janeiro - Brazil