# FileRealm Glassfish Authentication 4. Forward to specific page

Tags: glassfish

when i log from testlog.jsp and fill the form with incorrect password, i am moved to err.jsp. So authorization mechanism working good.
when i fill form with login and password correct i moved to index.jsp, but i want to moved to page git.html.

has somebody a similar project??

btw. i use glassfish 4.1 and netbeans 8.0.2.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>stronaretail</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/testlog.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/err.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Authorization Mechanism</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/git.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <group-name>admin</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279453/redirect-after-realm-authentication-on-glassfish?rq=1

Comment: exist any easier way??

Comment: you could try setting up a link re-direct within an element on the testlog.jsp page, so that after successful login the application will proceed to carry out that request of following the link. so I assume on /testlog.jsp you have a button or other element that the users clicks on to login with their entered credentials. so within the button tags add something like <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/git.html"/> this might forward onto that page if login successful

Comment: have you got any example code ??

Comment: I don't. I use spring-security to authenticate users and then forward to specific pages which is exemplified in the above link. The suggestion I gave you only requires that one line of code.

Comment: ok, i see. But form on the pge :    <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
            Username: <BR/>
            <input type="text" name="j_username" /> <BR/>
            <input type="text" name="j_password" /> <BR/>
            <input type="submit" value="Wyślij">
    </form> , and i don't know where i should i put Your line.

Comment: <form method="POST" action="j_security_check"> Username: <BR/> <input type="text" name="j_username" /> <BR/> <input type="text" name="j_password" /> <BR/><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/git.html"><input type="submit" value="Wyślij"></a></form>

Comment: this way the button/input looks like a button but acts like a hyperlink

Comment: when i fill the form with the corrects dates, i moved to index.jsp. Maybe do You have any idea??

Comment: change in web.xml: <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> to <welcome-file>git.html</welcome-file>

Comment: I can't change this atribute, because it tells application, that after write the address of application, you will forward to the indicated page