# Session always being created on login

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, authentication, cdi

Usually I use Java EE authentication with a custom login form and beans in my project. So I configure Glassfish to get user/password from a database (JDBC), create a jsf form that calls a login() method on a RequestScoped bean (named "LoginBean"), that calls HttpServletRequest's login() method.

When the login attempt succeeds, I set the user information in a SessionScoped bean that was injected in LoginBean, which I named "LoginService". And then, in lots of other website pages and beans I use this data by always injecting LoginService and acessing it's data.

All is fine, but I noticed that a Session is being created if a user goes to the login page, even if it hasn't attempted a login yet. My guess is that it happens because LoginService is injected in LoginBean always, on the object creation.

And because of that I have 2 questions:

1. Should I care about this session? Can this cause any problems?
2. What is the best way to do this custom login without creating a session every time a user access the login page? I mean, I could pass user info on a querystring after succeding, but that would be horrible. :)

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Should I care about this session? Can this cause any problems?*

Depends. If your server is on relatively "cheapass" hardware, then the chance on a successful DDOS attack is bigger because more sessions could be created than the server can destroy before the hardware limits are reached.

---

> *What is the best way to do this custom login without creating a session every time a user access the login page?*

Don't inject a session scoped bean. Put the `User` in session map yourself. See also "Update" part of [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147) for a concrete example:

```
public void login() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

    try {
        request.login(username, password);
        User user = userService.find(username, password);
        externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user);
        externalContext.redirect(originalURL);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // Handle unknown username/password in request.login().
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this with CDI I am a little doubtful about doing this with:

```
externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user);
```

I am not familiar with glassfish nor sure what "Java EE authentication" is about. So this is just my two cents being a CDI+tomcat user.

I would say that if you want to do this with CDI you should not have the bean be @SessionScoped seing how you need to control it more fine.

The userBean: I would go for `@WindowScoped` from myfaces CODI (will be included in deltaspike 0.4). I would have the loginBean be `@RequestScoped`. I would have a second loginBean `@ViewScoped` (myfaces codi required).

`@PreDestroy` could then be used on a method on our main loginBean. If authenticated ==  false we should destroy the `@windowScoped` bean.

The `@ViewScoped` bean is responsible for remembering number of failed login attempts and the username. Then again this is only if I would actually mind just creating the @WindowScoped bean (I don't for my projects)

Comment: Karl, I've been using Primefaces in all my projects. I'm not sure if I should add MyFaces so I can use @windowScoped, although it seems a good alternative to have a "more cdi" code (less coupling?). What do you think?

Comment: Myfaces CODI is a really nice addon to CDI (Codi and Seam 3 / Solder has now merged to Deltaspike project).

Using myfaces codi with CDI is a really good idea. And when Deltaspike 0.4 is ready you just switch into that.

Comment: Note that myfaces codi has a JSF-module. That module is independent of myfaces-jsf. It will work like a boss with mojarra jsf and primefaces as well.

Comment: Nice! I'll surelly take a look at it. Thank you.