# Java EE 6 security and redirection

Tags: java, security, jsf-2, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

I have a Java EE 6 web application running on JBoss 7.1.1 that has some pages that require authentication and many that do not. For the authenticated pages, I am using Servlet 3.0 Programmatic Security as described in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2207147/2133333).

In my web.xml, I have the following entry

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/loginError</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

and in my Login class, I have a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` where the page requested is captured:
`String previousURL = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_QUERY_STRING)`

However, it evaluates to the /login page itself rather than the page the user requested and was *then* forwarded to by JBoss because of the login-config settings in web.xml. As a result, when I forward to previousURL, it merely takes me back to the login page, rather than the page the user clicked on initially. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to retrieve the wrong attribute. What you're supposed to be trying to retrieve is the [RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI) which is an actual URI. What you're currently trying to retrieve is the query string (basically anything after the actual URL; the `?param=1` etc) following the requested url

Comment: Thanks for catching that. After changing it, I still get previousURL to the /login page rather than the page I requested initially.

Comment: And you're positive @Anand that the user credentials supplied are successfully authenticated?

Comment: I think so. Here's the log entry from JBoss: `Excuting query: select password from PRINCIPAL where username = ?, with username: admin
...
User 'admin' authenticated, loginOk=true
commit, loginOk=true  ...
Assign user to role Administration
...
User: admin is authenticated`