# Verifying additional parameter with j-security-check

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, j-security-check

I have implemented web application login using `j-security-check` which accepts parameters `j_username` and `j_password` for authentication with background registry. Now, I need to add date of birth as one more parameter and need to authenticate the user with this parameter too.

Is there a way to extend j-security-check to accept additional parameters?
I would like to avoid performing the check in a servlet filter, if possible.

Using WebSphere V8, MyFaces JSF 2.0, Servlet 3.0, Custom database based authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to append the date of birth to the actual `j_username` (ie. with JavaScript and then manually split it in the login module.

Comment: This can be an option. I was thinking to keep this as one of the last options :)

Comment: I faced this problem some time ago and simply haven't found any other solutions ;-)

Comment: I take this as a solution as I could not find any alternate option

Answer (score 1):

Replace `j_security_check` by programmatic login via `HttpServletRequest#login()`.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.username}" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{bean.password}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.birthdate}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{bean.login}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void login() {
    // Do your thing with birthdate here.

    // ...

    // Then perform programmatic login.
    try {
        request.login(username, password);
        // Login success. Redirect to landing page.
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // Login fail. Return to login page.
    }
}
```

This is in detail outlined in 2nd part of this answer: [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147)