# Accessing Glassfish container managed login page using iPhone Safari from outside LAN results in "server stopped responding" error

Tags: security, authentication, jsf-2, glassfish

### *Question*

How do I allow unauthenticated users to be served a login.xhtml JSF2.0 Facelet page over https when attempting access to security constrained resources or otherwise requiring login authentication.

### *Current Implementation*

I'm developing with NetBeans 7.3. Server is GlassFigh 3.1.2.2. Using PrimeFaces 3.5 components. Security is container managed under JDBCRealm. I have followed the pattern described very helpfully by BalusC's answer at [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0).

Basically:

- **Declarative Security using Deployment Descriptor**
- **Form based authentication** (Full JSF component Facelet login.xhtml using @ViewScoped @ManagedBean for programmatic login using Servlet 3.0 HttpServletRequest.login())
- **JDBC Realm**

Everything works great and as required when I run the program from the localhost machine or any machine over my LAN. The index.xhtml is the welcome file under my web.xml and it is also protected under a security constraint. Thus my

```
<form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
```

is presented when context root is hit from browser. The login.xhtml is also under a security constraint for the purpose of requiring CONFIDENTIAL under user-data-constraint. This successfully applies https for the login form which is how I'm answering my own question above.

### *Problem*

Whenever I try to load the page from my iPhone using standard Safari browser from outside my LAN (from the internet) i get a server stopped responding error after i see it switch my url from the http 8080 port to the https 8181 port. I also get a

> INFO: JACC Policy Provider:Failed Permission Check: context ("
>   WebApplication2/WebApplication2 ") , permission ("
>   ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/login.xhtml" "GET") ")

message in the netbeans glassfigh output window. Why does this not work the same as over a LAN?

### *Thoughts*

This current web.xml does not specify an auth-constraint element for the "secure login" security-constraint because the Java EE 6 Tutorial says "If there is no authorization constraint, the container must accept the request without requiring user authentication". If i specify an auth-constraint with a * role-name the application still behaves the same (same problem). Obviously if i give it an application role name the user could never be resolved to a role in the first place. Is this implementation pattern entirely wrong to begin with?

### *Code*

My web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>#{loggedInUser.preferences.theme}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>index</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>index</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/index.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>secure login</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>login.xhtml</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/login.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the edit. I see the new title clearly states the problem. Should I instead write a very simple question without an example of my current attempt for a solution and associated problem? e.g. "How to specify a secure connection on a login page for unauthenticated users in Java EE6?".