# can I write actionListner or action for <h:commandButton type =submit>

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, j-security-check, commandbutton

I need to execute a backing bean method using a `<h:commandButton type="submit">` in the following form:

```
<h:form id="login" prependId="false" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';">

    <h:commandButton type="submit">  

</h:form>
```

I tried to define `action` as well as `actionListner`, however the backing bean method is never executed. How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

It failed because you changed the form action URL to a non-JSF URL. That URL never hits the `FacesServlet` and hence it won't be able to decode, queue and invoke the command button action. Get rid of the `onsubmit` attribute altogether (and preferably also the `prependId`). It'll then submit to a proper JSF URL and invoke the command button action.

```
<h:form id="login">
```

If you intend to perform container managed authentication using JSF, then head to the following answer: [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147) to learn how to use `j_security_check` properly without the need for a JSF command button action, and also to do it programmatically in a JSF command button action method instead of attempting to submit straight to `j_security_check`.

The `<h:commandButton type>` defaults by the way already to `submit`. Just don't repeat the defaults and keep it out your code to keep it short and clean.