# (Why do I get) Error forwarding/redirecting to login page when not using AJAX after configuring to handle exceptions when using AJAX (using OmniFaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have a a JSF application running on Glassfish [GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5); Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206)].  I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 and OmniFaces version 1.5.  I am using form-based login authentication

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>reportingRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

have defined an error page in web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/faces/viewExpired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

and have the following URL pattern for servlet mapping (in case it is relevant)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The application originally was not using AJAX.  Specifically, I had a p:commandButton that did not use AJAX.  If the session expired and this button was clicked, exception handling proceeded as follows:  the login page was displayed; on (re)entering login credentials and logging in, the session expired page was shown.  Choosing to log in again put you back in business.  I don't have any issue with this.  (Note that originally I believe that I specifically referenced ViewExpiredException in error-page, and not Throwable as it is now configured.  The behavior(s) that I describe occur both when Throwable is used and when ViewExpiredException was used, with the caveat that in the case of ViewExpiredException I added an additional exception type to satisfy an OmniFaces requirement).

I changed the application to use AJAX when the p:commandButton was clicked.  In support of this, I added OmniFaces (a solution that I highly recommend) to my project, and also changed form-login-page from '/login.xhtml' to '/faces/login.xhtml' (as I understood the OmniFaces documentation, and given my configuration, this would be necessary; in fact, with form-login-page equal to '/login.xhmtl', exception handling continued to work as before when using a non-AJAX enabled control, but nothing would happen when clicking on an AJAX-enabled control (no change to the displayed page and nothing logged)).

With the p:commandButton using AJAX, OmniFaces in use, and form-login-page changed to '/faces/login.xhtml', when the session expired and I click on an AJAX-enabled control, the ViewExpiredException handling works perfectly (in fact, I prefer the sequence that occurs over the sequence that occurs when ViewExpiredException is handled for a non-AJAX enabled control: the sequence with OmniFaces is you are taken directly to the session expired page.  Choose to log in again and you are back in business.)

However, now - if the session has expired and I click on a non-AJAX enabled control - the following is displayed (as the only content on the page now displayed) in my browser window

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:8080/Reporting-war/faces/protected/multiUser.xhtml
Line Number 1, Column 1;
```

The following is logged:

```
WARNING: ApplicationDispatcher[/Reporting-war] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

WARNING: Unexpected error forwarding or redirecting to login page
javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login.xhtml - View /login.xhtml could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
...
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    ... 32 more
```

Note that with form-login-page having the value '/faces/login.xhtml', the error occurs whether or not OmniFaces is in use; I do not believe that this is an OmniFaces issue.  However, I do not understand (a) why it is happening, or (b) whether there is a way that I can maintain my existing configuration (for example, keeping my servlet-mapping, etc.) and get session expired handling to work both for AJAX-enabled and non-AJAX enabled controls.

multiUser.xhtml begins as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="./mainTemplate.xhtml"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <ui:define name="top">
    </ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
...
```

login.xhtm, in full, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
            Username
            <input type="text" name="j_username"/>
            Password
            <input type="password" name="j_password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

viewExpired.xhtml, in full, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <title>Expired Session</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                Your login session has expired.
            </p>
            <p>
                <h:form>
                    <h:link value="Login Again" outcome="home"/>
                </h:form>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help that anyone can give with understanding why this is happening, and with understanding what the options are for addressing it, would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The concrete problem is caused because the average container by default saves POST data of POST requests which hit FORM based authentication. This POST data (all POST request parameters) are restored when FORM based authentication succeeds. The JSF `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden field value is also present in the POST data.

As the FORM based authentication is performed by POST and the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden field value is present in the request parameter map, the `FacesContext#isPostback()` evaluates true during `RestoreViewPhase#execute()` and thus JSF will attempt to actually restore the view instead of creating a new one. However, as the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden field is actually referring the old view state of the previous session, which does not exist in the current session anymore, a `ViewExpiredException` is thrown.

This is an unfortunate problem. Basically, the Servlet API and JSF API are in collision with each other. There are basically 2 solutions:

1. Tell the container to not save POST data for FORM based authentication. For Tomcat and clones, that's a matter of setting `maxSavePostSize` attribute of [`<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) element in `/conf/server.xml` to `-1`.

   ```xml
   <Connector ... maxSavePostSize="-1">
   ```

   For Glassfish 3.x, sorry I have no idea! I peeked around in its documentation, but I don't immediately see anything which comes close.
2. Don't use `j_security_check`. Use programmatic authentication instead with a true JSF form and a true backing bean. This allows more fine grained control over handling a successful login. For an elaborate code snippet, check the 2nd half of this answer, starting with "Update": [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147) This won't continue the POST request with restored POST data, but just send a true redirect on the request URI.

It works for ajax requests because the login page is opened by a redirect as instructed by the ajax response of OmniFaces. So at the point the FORM based authentication check is hit, there is basically no means of any POST data which needs to be saved.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and for taking the time to explain the problem and options.  Very much appreciated.