# Programmatic login on glassfish

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish

As shown in
[Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0)
and
[this blog post](http://jugojava.blogspot.de/2011/07/jsf-form-authentication-on-servlet-3.html)
I'm trying to login in my server using programmatic login, but I'm having some difficulties.
I first implemented it with the standard FORM method, and everything worked (so the server should be correctly configured)
But after I implemented it with the method shown above, I'm no longer able to log.
I'm sure the registration is right as I can see in the database the right informations.

This is my bean code

```
@ManagedBean(name="logBean")
@ViewScoped
public class LogBean {

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String originalURL;

    @EJB
    private UserCredentialManager userMgr;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext();
        originalURL = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(
                RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

        if (originalURL == null) {
            originalURL = externalContext.getRequestContextPath()
                    + "/home.xhtml";
        } else {
            String originalQuery = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap()
                    .get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_QUERY_STRING);

            if (originalQuery != null) {
                originalURL += "?" + originalQuery;
            }
        }
    }

    public String login() throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        try {
            request.login(email, password);
            System.out.println("Login Succesfull: " + email);
            if(originalURL == null) {
                UserDTO userDTO = userMgr.getUserDTO();
                if(userDTO.getIsClient()) {
                    return "/cliente/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
                } else {
                    return "/impiegato/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
                }
            } else {
                return originalURL + "?faces-redirect=true";
            }
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            return "/loginError.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

    public String logout() throws IOException {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        try {
            request.logout();
            externalContext.invalidateSession();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO gestisci il fallimento di logout.
            // Probabilmente manda un messaggio.
            System.out.println("Logout failed for " + request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
        }
        return "/home?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is the login.xhtml

```
<h:head>
    <title>Login</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:panel header="Login Form">
        <h:panelGrid colums = "2" id = "login_grid">
            <h:outputLabel for="email">Email:</h:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText id="email" value="#{logBean.email}" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password">Password:</h:outputLabel>
            <p:password id="password" value="#{logBean.password}" label="Password"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Log In" update="login_grid"
                action="#{logBean.login()}" />
        <h:form rendered="#{param['cliente']}">
            <h:link value="Register" outcome="register" />
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This is the web.xml

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>travelDreamRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

Whenever I try to access a protected page I'm correctly redirected to the login page, but unfortunately the log in is never successful. What am I doing wrong? I suspect something with the web.xml, but I haven't found a single informations bout what tags I should set and how.
I'm always getting a `WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception`

I'm working with glassfish 4.0, java ee 6

Answer (score 0):

Did you run your in debug and checked the variables values of *email* and *password* passed to *request.login()* method ?
I have the exatly same code in my project and it works like a charm.