# get j_username in j_security_check JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, j-security-check

I have simple page, I want to retrieve `j_username` to save it in session as a logged in user, i can't fetch it from the form. here Server it self perform authentication in this code

```
<h:form id="login" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';" prependId="false">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
                    <p:inputText id="j_username" name="j_username"/>            
                    <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
                    <p:password id="j_password" name="j_password" value=""/>
                    <p:commandButton style="font-size:15px" type="submit"  value="Login" ajax="false"/>
                    <p:commandButton style="font-size:15px" type="clear" value="Clear" ajax="false"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available by [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29) which is in JSF context delegated by [`ExternalContext#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

So, this should do either in the view:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{empty request.remoteUser}">
    <p>This is only rendered when someone's NOT logged in.</p>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty request.remoteUser}">
    <p>This is only rendered when someone's been logged in.</p>
    <p>Welcome, you're logged in as #{request.remoteUser}!</p>
</ui:fragment>
```

or in the managed bean:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
String username = ec.getRemoteUser();
// ...
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: it's better to get rid of that `onsubmit` nonsense and just use plain `<form>` instead of `<h:form>`.

```
<form id="login" action="j_security_check">
```

This way it'll also work on JS-disabled clients.

#### See also:

- [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147)

Comment: Due to proxy settings on localhost it was null, on server works fine. Thanks BalusC for reply and help