# OmniFaces Extensionless URLs and login redirect

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I have configured my application to use [OmniFaces's Extensionless URLs](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs) feature, but now that I enabled security in my `web.xml`, the extensionless requests do not get caught by the `<security-constraint>`.

**web.xml**

```
<!-- JSF configuration -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- OmniFaces configuration -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Servlets and filters. -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Welcome files, error pages and mime types. -->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Security constraints -->

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Allowed resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>SSL transport</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- Security roles -->

<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
</security-role>

<!-- Login config -->

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputText value="Username:" />
        <h:inputText id="username" required="true"
            value="#{appSession.loginUsername}"
            requiredMessage="Username is required" />
        <h:message for="username" />
        <hr />

        <h:outputText value="Password:" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" required="true"
            value="#{appSession.loginPassword}"
            requiredMessage="Password is required" />
        <h:message for="password" />

        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{appSession.login}" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:messages globalOnly="true" showDetail="false" />
</h:form>
```

**AppSession.java**

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class AppSession {

    private String loginUsername;
    private String loginPassword;

    public AppSession() {   }

    public String login() {
        try {
            Faces.login(loginUsername, loginPassword);

            return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return "login.xhtml";
        }
    }

    public void logout() throws IOException {
        Faces.invalidateSession();
        Faces.redirect("index.xhtml");
    }

    //Getters and setters

}
```

So, if I browse to `index.xhtml`, it gets redirected correctly to `login`. However if I browse to `index`, there is no redirect and the browser is allowed to download the content from `index`. I know that this is exactly what is specified in `web.xml` by `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`, but how can I configure the application, so that extensionless URLs get also restricted by login?

If I try this with `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` under `<security-constraint>`, it gets redirected successfully, however my login form does not work in this case. I have to do programmatic login with JSF, since I want to reuse the credentials for webservices. Any ideas so I get a valid configuration?

I am using OmniFaces 2.0, Mojarra 2.2.7 on GlassFish 4.1.

Comment: The `/*` should work. I've pinged Arjan on this.

Comment: I am redirected successfully to the login page (using `<param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>`), when a page from a secure area is attempted without having an extension. (Inside `<web-resource-collection>`, I am using directory level mappings (thus not extension mappings) such as `<url-pattern>/xxx_yyy_zzz/*</url-pattern>`. Using OmniFaces 1.8.1, JSF 2.3.0-m01, GlassFish 4.1, PrimeFaces 5.1). (I however, get an exception while redirecting to a home page after successful login which is a special case associated with my application only and still to be debugged. Thus, it was not taken into account)

Comment: Upgraded the library OmniFaces 1.8.1 to OmniFaces 2.0 and the result is the same as the preceding comment.

Comment: @BalusC Extended the question so there is more info about the case.

Comment: Can you clarify "login form does not work" in developer's perspective?

Comment: @BalusC When the application is opened, I get redirected to `/login`. If I hit submit, the page is reloaded, but `#{appSession.login}` is definitely not triggered. Sounds like `facesServlet` is not kicking in (it is set to `*.xhtml`). I have tried to disable the Extensionless URLs feature, and the login worked again from `/login.xhtml`.

Comment: @BalusC SSCCE (Eclipse project): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14670704/OmniExtensionlessLogin.zip

Comment: I very quickly glanced at your SSCCE, but noticed several things like 2 templates, the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` in faces-config.xml, a few `styleClass` attributes, a lot of options in web.xml like `javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD` and even the PrimeFaces 'FileUploadFilter'. Are all of those really necessary to reproduce the problem? I.e. since you included the Ajax exception handler in the SSCCE, does that mean everything works if you omit that one? And same question for the PrimeFaces filter, why did you include it? Does everything work without it?

Comment: @ArjanTijms You are right, I didn't take _short_ seriously enough :) I have removed the things you mentioned and updated the SSCCE (still available @ above link. The symptoms still exist.

Comment: It appears that you're mixing container managed login and programmatic login.

Comment: @BalusC Can you clarify this; You mean because of `j_username`, `j_password`? I have changed those and still have the problem. Also updated the SSCCE.

Comment: @DanielSzalay I think BalusC refers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546511/get-j-username-in-j-security-check-jsf-2-0 if you use Servlet's FORM your /login page needs to post to "j_security_check", you are posting back to /login and then logging in programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is fixed if I add `login` and `login.xhtml` to allowed resources:

```
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Allowed resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
```