# Ajax request after session timeout shows <partial-response>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

Omnifaces 2.0, Primefaces 5, wildFly 8.2

After session timeout if I try to make an ajax call with registered `FullAjaxExceptonHandler` in browser will be shown xml response and not the rendered error page.

The similiar error comes if `PrimeExceptionHandler` is used. If both excepton handlers are removed the similiar incorrect output in browser and exception comes. See *EDIT* browser output.

**EDIT 2** If the rows in `web.xml` are changed to "JSP" Login

```
        <form-login-page>/login/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login/login.jsp</form-error-page>
```

then  AjaxExceptionHandler is not called.

login.xhtml is very similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2207147/2023524 . Only with RequestScope and stateless view.

**output in browser**:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewRoot"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            text of ErrorHandlerViewExpired.xhtml ...

</html></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">stateless</update></changes></partial-response>
```

web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>app</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errors/errorHandlerWeb.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/errorHandlerViewExpired.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/errorHandlerProg.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<factory>
   <exception-handler-factory>
      org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
   </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

Console:

```
FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/errors/errorHandlerViewExpired.xhtml?faces-redirect=true' will be shown.: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/login/login.xhtml - Ansicht /login/login.xhtml konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:212) [jsf-impl-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.11.jar:2.2.11]
```

**EDIT**

**Output in browser without some ajaxExceptionHandler**:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
  <redirect url="/app/pageWithAjax.jsf"/>
    <error>
    <error-name>class javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</error-name>
     <error-message>viewId:/login/login.xhtml - Ansicht /login/login.xhtml konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden.
     </error-message></error></partial-response>
```

Comment: Is this a restricted page with login? How are you authenticating users? Spring Security? Regardless, it's the authentication framework who's incorrectly re-executing the JSF ajax request instead of creating a new GET request.

Comment: The page is restricted with "FORM" authentication. The users are authenticated over JSF Login backing bean. (Standard Java EE)Login view is "login/login.xhtml". Then it should be `WildFly` that makes trouble. Please also see update

Comment: I have re-read the question and got a bit confused on the exact use case. Do I understand this right: 1) You've a restricted JSF page open in browser. 2) Session gets expired in background. 3) You fire an ajax request on that restricted JSF page. 4) You see <partial-response> with contents of `errorHandlerViewExpired.xhtml` plain in browser. Is this sequence correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I open restricted page `/app/pagesWithAjax.xhtml`. The page is open in browser and after session timeout I click on `p:dataTable` with ajax event on row. Then in browser I see <partial-response>.

Comment: This is indeed not the expected behavior. I will later try to reproduce.

Comment: Someone else reported the same problem today and I have reproduced it on WildFly 10.0.0 and fixed it for OmniFaces 2.3-SNAPSHOT. Can you please try it as well? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35841356

Answer (score 0):

The right solution with Omnifaces is described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35843836/2023524

---

Here is a solution for one concrete situation, only if user loged in with Java EE loging and want to redirect to error page and not to login page.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler;
import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;

public class CustomExceptionViewExpiredHandler extends FullAjaxExceptionHandler{

    public CustomExceptionViewExpiredHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
            boolean b = handleViewExpiredException(Faces.getContext());
            if (!b)
                return;
            super.handle();

    }

    private boolean handleViewExpiredException (FacesContext context){
        if (context == null || !context.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
            return false; // Not an ajax request.
        }

        //Test user Principal, java authentication
        if (Faces.getSession() == null || Faces.getRequest().getUserPrincipal() == null){
            try {
                String errorPageLocation = findErrorPageLocation(context, new SomeSessionExpiredException());

                Faces.redirect(Faces.getRequestContextPath() + errorPageLocation);
                Faces.responseComplete();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```