# JSF show <partial-response> page after get request

Tags: jsf, wildfly, security-constraint, partial-response

i have a problem while session expired and i make GET request, instead page i see xml file. How i can colve this problem ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Answer depends on authentication framework and appserver you're using. It is re-executing the last security-blocked request as a synchronous request after successful login/rememberme. However, that fails for JSF ajax requests as you see.

Comment: WildFly 9.0.1 with realm ldap authentication.

Comment: Does this explain/solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35841356