# Widlfy 22 WELD Warnings with Form Based Programmatically Login

Tags: authentication, wildfly, cdi, jsf-2.3, servlet-4

I have a web application currently deployed on Wildfly 22, using JSF 2.3 and OpenJDK 11.
I'm currently migrating the login page from j_security_check to a programmatically login, following BalusC example on this post:

**[Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/performing-user-authentication-in-java-ee-jsf-using-j-security-check)**

I'm not posting the login code, because it's exactly like BalusC post.

The login process is working just fine, however after this change i'm getting two warnings on Wildfly.

```
WELD-000717: Unable to deactivate context org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.LazyHttpConversationContextImpl@14d2bf9d when destroying request HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /app/login/login.xhtml ]
```

```
WELD-000335: Conversation context is already active, most likely it was not cleaned up properly during previous request processing: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /app/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css]
```

Any hints on what's causing these warnings?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Same in java8 wildfly20

Comment: did you found a solution or the reason for that warning - same in Wildfly 25

Comment: Unfortunately no, i didn't find a solution. The problem still remains using Wildfly 26.

Comment: I discovered this issue as well and opened an issue in the Wildfly jira: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15972
This still exists in 26.0.1 and does exist since 20 it seems.

Comment: I do have the same issue after migrating from wildfly 8 to Wildfly 25. OpenJdk 11 as well.