# Apache MyFaces 2.0 authentication and authorization

Tags: java, authentication, jsf-2, authorization

I need to create a webapp that has a login system.
the user should authenticate against a database.
I want to save the userrole in session - or are there other (better) ways?

Furthermore there are areas for user access. 
Guest area,
user area,
admin area.

The question now is.
How can I easily implement the authorization with jsf2.0?
I don't want to test on each site, if the user is permitted to acces the site or not.

Is there a configuration in web.xml or faces-config.xml that test the cases?

Can someone show me a tutorial or sample code?

Thanks and best regards
veote

Comment: Websphere Application Server 8.0

Comment: "I don't want to test on each site, if the user is permitted to acces the site or not." can you elaborate 'each site', are you looking single point authentication for multiple sites? or did you mean checking on each page/link ??

Comment: [link @ SO might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187949/jsf-authentication-and-authorization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also look at options (Framewroks)

> 1. [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)
> 2. [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)
> 3. [Java EE Security Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html)
> 4. As already suggested Application Server provided Authentication/Authorization.
> 5. Implement a Filter (Custom home grown logic for Authentication/Authorization)

Blogs covering AnA in JSF

> 1. [User session filter](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/03/user-session-filter.html)
> 2. [Access Control in JSF using a PhaseListener](http://devgrok.blogspot.in/2009/07/access-control-using-phaselistener.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't know Apache Shiro, is it worth to try?Especially in comparison with Spring Security(if you have experience with both of them)

Comment: @PetrMensik I havent tried it but as seen in blogs and at times at SO its definitely worth a try people do use it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think shiro is what I wanted. I will try this

Comment: @veote you are welcome, you can mark my reply as answer to your question, I'll gain some points ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://devgrok.blogspot.com/2009/07/access-control-using-phaselistener.html) approach, it uses PhaseListener to check if user has rights for accessing current site during the RESTORE_VIEW phase. It is quite easy to implement it and it's portable between different servers(opposite from realms)

Comment: Thanks, that seems nice. Is there maybe another way to configure this in web.xml / faces-config?

Comment: Well, not really in such a good manner. You can specify the restricted pages and how to log the user, but it usually works fine only with realms(and that is sometimes hard to set it all up and wire it together). And BTW, why do you want use just these xml files?Seems to me more cleaner and readeble to stick with classic programming style instead of bothering yourself with XML

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Websphere, but since it is a Java EE 6 compliant application server, you can create a JDBCRealm for this purpose. See this chapter of the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxgo.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I for me it's not the best way I think, because maybe I want to change the db with a ldap.

Comment: @veote I use weblogic but changing authentication provider in a realm is not that hard you can switch technologies with ease.

Comment: If you look at the example in the tutorial (and from my experience), I agree with gbagga that switching should not be that complicated.