# Authentication in Java EE Application

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to achieve user authentication at `EJB` level? 
All resources and tutorials I found say ho to do this in servlets (`HttpServletRequest`)... My application is based on couple **JSF** pages and one servlet. All I want to do is to authenticate user via JSF page and remember authentication across all application until user logs out or close browser. Moreover I prefer to stick to "raw" `Java EE` and not use any frameworks.

It seems to be still very unclear for me after I read many articles and question at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of choices, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738114/apache-myfaces-2-0-authentication-and-authorization/9738387#9738387). But of all these solutions applies to JSF layer, I don't think you can have direct validation from your JSF/JSP pages to EJB beans(and I don't see why would you want to, because all of above are 100% Java EE solution).

But if want to secure your EJB methods and classes against unathorized access then [here](http://vikaskumar9.blogspot.com/2011/02/ejb-31-security-example.html) is a small example how to do that